# My library membership number

Tags: mathematics, primes

My library membership number, which I readily forget, is a 10-digit number, all different digits. However, I do remember it is the largest such number in which any block of four adjacent digits is either a prime or a perfect square.

What is it?

(Preferably no computers except to find list of squares and primes)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that there is such a number? I ask because (1) I think I have a proof that there isn't and (2) a computer search (conducted in such a way as to avoid showing me the answer if it succeeded) didn't find one. I am extremely fallible so despite #1 and #2 I think the error is probably mine, but could you double-check anyway? Thanks.

Comment: You are right. My alleged membership number with the property I describe is no such. Sorry!

Comment: If you would like to adjust the question to ask whether there is such a number or not, I can tweak my part-written answer to explain why the answer is no :-).

Comment: (But I think we have found the explanation for why you "readily forget" the number.)

Comment: ... Or, y'know, some other person could come in and drop an answer also explaining why the answer is no, without reading the comments and seeing that this was already known and only not posted because of an ongoing discussion with the OP :-).

Comment: (I posted my answer anyway. _I_ know I was there first :-).)

Answer (score 15):

The number

> does not in fact exist.

Explanation:

> The digits 0, 2, and 8 can't be at the end of any block of 4 since no 4-digit prime ends with any of them, no square ends with 2 or 8, and any square ending 0 actually ends 00. So 0,2,8 (in some order) are the *first three* digits, the only ones that don't end any 4-digit block.

Now

> Let's think about the 4-digit square ending in 5. Obviously this must be a square since no 4-digit prime ends in 5. Any 4-digit square is the square of a 2-digit number between 32 and 99; this one must be the square of 35, 45, ..., 95. These squares are 1225, 2025, 3025, 4225, 5625, 7225, 9025. The only ones without repeated digits are 3025 and 9025. But these are impossible because each of them has a 0 appearing *after* a non-{0,2,8} digit.

Comment: Since the squares of ?5 end in 25 then the first 4 digits must be 8025.

Comment: Yes, that's another nice way to do the last bit.

Answer (score 6):

> No such number exists.

> All digits in the resultant number starting from the $4^{th}$ number must be the end of some "block".

> Primes can end with any odd digit, and out of the even digits, perfect squares can end only with $0$, $6$ and $4$. But even $0$ is not possible, because only for multiples of $10$ the squares end with a $0$, which means the square must have atleast $2$ zeroes at the end, but that would break the all distinct digits condition.

> So the digits $0$, $2$ and $8$ cannot be the end of some block so these must be the first $3$ digits in some order. Let us try all paths we can take in decreasing order and see if we can reach a number. Basically we should choose the next digit such that last $4$ digits form a prime/perfect square and the digits are all distinct.

> 820 -> **8209** -> X

> 802 -> X

> 280 -> **2809**/**2803**/**2801**
>  **2809** -> 2**8093** -> 28**0937** -> 280**9371** -> X
>  **2803** -> 2**8039** -> 28**0397** -> X
>  **2801** -> 2**8017** -> 28**0179**/28**0173**
>  28**0179** -> X
>  28**0173** -> X

> 208 -> **2089** / **2087** / **2083** / **2081**
>  **2089** -> X
>  **2087** -> X
>  **2083** -> 2**0839** -> X
>  **2081** -> X

> 082 -> **0829** / **0827** / **0823** / **0821**
>  **0829** -> 0**8297** / 0**8293** / 0**8291**
>  0**8297** -> 08**2971** -> X
>  0**8293** -> X
>  0**8291** -> 08**2917** / 08**2916**
>  08**2917** -> 082**9173** -> X
>  08**2916** -> X
>  **0827** -> 0**8273** -> 08**2731** -> X
>  **0823** -> 0**8237**/0**8231**
>  0**8237** -> 08**2371** -> 082**3719** -> X
>  0**8231** -> X
>  **0821** -> 0**8219** -> X

> 028 -> **0289** / **0283** / **0281**
>  **0289** -> 0**2897** -> 02**8971** -> X
>  **0283** -> 0**2837** -> X
>  **0281** -> 0**2819** -> X

> All paths end with a dead end which indicates there isn't a valid number satisfying the conditions. Assuming I did not end up with a mistake at any step.